# Linux sort Command: how to sort on a number embedded in a field?

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm on RHEL 6 using BASH.

I'm trying to sort some lines in a file, by a number that is embedded in a field.   The name of the file is word.txt.

This is the command I am using:

```
sort -n -k4 word.txt
```

This is the output I am getting, not in numerical order:

```
INSERT INTO area_names VALUES(124,'NewYork');
INSERT INTO area_names VALUES(125,'NewYork');
INSERT INTO area_names VALUES(12,'NewYork');
```

Obviously, the line with just "12" should be first.

The number after "VALUES(" can be of any length

How can I tell sort to sort on the number in between "VALUES(" and "," ?

I can fall back on a workaround of putting a white space after "VALUES(" in the data, but I would rather not do that unless that is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 sort -t "(" -k2,2 -n word.txt
```

Output

```
INSERT INTO area_names VALUES(12,'NewYork');
INSERT INTO area_names VALUES(124,'NewYork');
INSERT INTO area_names VALUES(125,'NewYork');
```

---

```
-k POS1[,POS2]

     Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between
     POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted),
     _inclusive_.

     Each POS has the form `F[.C][OPTS]', where F is the number of the
     field to use, and C is the number of the first character from the
     beginning of the field.  Fields and character positions are
     numbered starting with 1; a character position of zero in POS2
     indicates the field's last character.  If `.C' is omitted from
     POS1, it defaults to 1 (the beginning of the field); if omitted
     from POS2, it defaults to 0 (the end of the field).  OPTS are
     ordering options, allowing individual keys to be sorted according
     to different rules; see below for details.  Keys can span multiple
     fields.

     Example:  To sort on the second field, use `--key=2,2' (`-k 2,2').
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. What is happening with the ",2" in -k2,2 ?  The MAN page doesn't say much about that.

Comment: I've added text from `info sort`.

Comment: Thanks, I just used the manpage and "info" didn't occur to me